# MediaWiki on Subdomain (.htaccess rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I am using an Apache Server (cant config apache root files) and running my core website (Invision Power) in the root domain "**example.com**". We decided to expand our services with a wiki using MediaWiki which is installed and can currently be reached on "example.com/w/".

I am utterly noobish with .htacess and Rewrite Conds/Rules and looking for help! We want our wiki to be access via **wiki.example.com** - and this URL should NOT change in the adressbar. Each page (wiki.example.com/Main_Page) should be accessed like this.

**Please keep in mind** that we want our core website keep working as it did for years now. So example.com and any other folders should not be affected by the Rewrite Rule.

Can someone please help - do you need any further information??

THANK YOU SO MUCH
Best Regards

Comment: So, what have You try so far?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing I think that is close to the final solution. I am really unexperienced with .htaccess